# scala create val for outer scope

Tags: scala

Consider following object,

```
    object A {
        def setX(x:Int) = {
            val x1 = x
        }

        def getx() = x1
    }
```

If I create val x1 inside setX that's scope will be the method setX. what I really want to do is **create a val outside the method and assign the value inside the method**. Is it impossible without using var, or is there any way to do it?

Please send me an example if you can.

Comment: What do you want to happen if getx() is called before setX()?  There are lots of ways to do what I think you're trying to do, but your example is basically asking for mutable state without mutable state.

Comment: And what should happen when you call `setX` twice? Should the `val` *change*? Bad. Should it be ignored? Also bad. Should it result in an error? Probably the best, but still not nice.

Comment: Actually, this is for a scalaquery project and i didn't want to put a messy scalaquery code in this example, this method is to set the database and i can guarantee that, setX is called once for the runtime. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is sort of the difference between `val` ("readonly") and `var`.

So no: not possible.

If the problem (not the desired solution) is explained more, there might be alternative approaches.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell, what you actually want to achieve, but often converting your `setX` method does the trick:

```
   def setX(x:Int) = {
       x
   }

   val x1 = setX(x)
```

or you could create a `SetOnce` class which holds a value and allows to set it exactly once ...